# Converting CharacterArray to ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a String i needed to add the individual characters of that String into an ArrayList.

For Ex:String str="hello world";

Step 1:I am Splitting that String into charArray();

```
 char ch[]=str.toCharArray();
```

Step 2:I am Converting that char Array into List and i am typecasting into an ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Character> ar=new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList(ch));
```

Step 3:I am trying to Iterate and print those elements.

```
Iterator i=ar.iterator();
while(i.hasNext())
{
  System.out.println(i.next());
}
```

I am expecting 'h' ,'e','l','l','o','','w','o','r','l','d' to be printed.

But instead it is printing some object address [[C@f0d1e0b]

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Do you mean that Characters are primitive types so it can't be Stored in an ArrayList as Objects

Comment: `char` is a primitive type. `asList` expects a `T[]` and `char` cannot be a used as the type inferred for `T` because it is a primitive type. So Java instead infers `char[]`  as the substitute for `T`. Also, `new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList(ch));` won't compile so I don't know how you got the result you showed us.

Comment: The duplicates go into much more detail about what happens

Comment: @Solitiros Delimanolis I got your point.Tanx for your point